# how to performed multiple action on one button.if i click "add"first time label will show on top of Frame,then bottom,then left, on fourth click right

Tags: java

**how to performed multiple action using one button in Java, i want to click only one button.when i click second,third,fourth time the label will be show on bottom,left,top,right side**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class labelmooving extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    Label l;
    Button b;
    labelmooving(){
        setLayout(null);
        b=new Button("Enter");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        b.setBounds(210,200,60,60);
        add(b);
        l=new Label("Hello");
        l.setBounds(30,50,100,30);
        add(l);
    }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==b){
            l.setBounds(350,50,100,30);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        labelmooving obj=new labelmooving();
        obj.setSize(500,500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setLocation(400,150);
    }
}
```

Comment: take some `int` variable to check which click is this and show your label accordingly.

Comment: Can you please show it by code

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can implement your situation.

```
int position = 0; //this will tell where to position label.

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==b){
        if(position == 0){
              //position at top
              l.setBounds(350,50,100,30);
        }
        else if(position == 1){
              //position at bottom
        }
        else if(position == 2){
              //position at left
        }
        else if(position == 3){
              //position at right

        }
        position = (position + 1) % 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: if still not running let me know.